# Synchronize WPF ColorAnimation across several controls

Tags: wpf, animation, synchronization, styles

I have several toggle-like buttons that I want to pulsate in unison when in the pressed state.

I have defined a style with a trigger that kicks-off the glow animation and this works just fine, apart from the fact that each button pulsates asynchronously from the others.

How can I have each button synchronize its pulse to the others?

Here's the style:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="pulseStory">
    <ColorAnimation                                                                    
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    From="Red"
                    To="Transparent"
                    Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>

<Style x:Key="pulseButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource pulseStory}"/>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you should be doing this via a resource, at least using a hidden control is a bit too much of a hack for me personally.

What needs to be met for it to work:

1. The property you bind to needs to be a DependencyProperty, hence your enveloping object needs to be a DependencyObject.
2. You have to reference the object as a static resource (as opposed to a dynamic resource) like this:

```
<DoubleAnimation
    Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource AnimationValue}"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(local:WrappedValue.Value)"
    To="0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
```

Well, admittedly it's a bit hacky as well to have a Wrapper-class for this but it's cleaner than a full control (if you want to use controls you can utilize some unused `Tag`-property, e.g. of the container that hosts all your controls)

Comment: Haven't thought about this  - will give it a go as well.

Answer (score 4):

OK ... I'll take a stab at this one ...

The WPF framework doesn't have any facility for synchronizing animations that are running concurrently, so you are going to have to come up with a different method. One idea springs to mind ...

Animate some Color property of a hidden UI element within your storyboard, then use UI binding (i.e. ElementName bindings) to connect to the Color of each of your buttons to this hidden UI element.

Comment: Cool - all it takes is 17 hours and you can answer your own questions ;-) I'll try to be a bit quicker next time!